# Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesBetaDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-viewbinding

**Error : Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesBetaDebug'.

> not a valid name: switch

**

after updating android studio to version  4.2.1  unable to run build.

buildFeatures {
viewBinding true
}

**ERROR Detail :**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesBetaDebug'.
  not a valid name: switch

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a valid name: switch
at com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:53)
at com.squareup.javapoet.FieldSpec.builder(FieldSpec.java:91)
at android.databinding.tool.ext.Javapoet_extKt.fieldSpec(javapoet_ext.kt:60)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator.bindingFields(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:102)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator.access$bindingFields(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:52)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator$typeSpec$1.invoke(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:81)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator$typeSpec$1.invoke(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:52)
at android.databinding.tool.ext.Javapoet_extKt.classSpec(javapoet_ext.kt:39)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator.typeSpec(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:73)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.JavaFileGenerator.create(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:69)
at android.databinding.tool.writer.ViewBinderGenerateJavaKt.toJavaFile(ViewBinderGenerateJava.kt:43)
at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder$generateAll$2.accept(BaseDataBinder.kt:82)
at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder$generateAll$2.accept(BaseDataBinder.kt:34)
at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder.generateAll(BaseDataBinder.kt:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$CodeGenerator.run(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:228)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$writeBaseClasses$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:67)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)